# Unable to kickstart machine with spacewalk / 404 squashfs.img

Tags: kickstart, squashfs, cobbler, spacewalk

I am using spacewalk 2.6 on a CentOS7 machine.
I am trying to kickstart machine from the spacewalk server.

For troubleshooting purposes, i have

- disabled SElinux
- no iptabled/firewalld

I have tried creating an installable tree during the syncing of channel/repo of a CentOS7. After the distribution is added in spacewalk, is set the installer generation to Red Hat Linux 7. I have also mounted an iso of a netinstall iso of SL, and copied its content to the spcewalk server to create a distribution in Spacewalk

I create a kickstart in the GUI of spacewalk, all fine and well.

When i kickstart a machine, it fails because it cannot find `LiveOS/squashfs.img`. The file is there on the server, but the httpd gives an 404. I tried to widen the permission on the LiveOS folder in the kickstart tree but no dice.

```
10.10.70.8 - - [15/Jan/2017:12:39:00 +0100] "POST /cobbler_api HTTP/1.1" 200 143 "-" "Java/1.8.0_111"
10.10.70.8 - - [15/Jan/2017:12:39:00 +0100] "POST /cobbler_api HTTP/1.1" 200 129 "-" "Java/1.8.0_111"
10.10.10.6 - - [15/Jan/2017:12:39:00 +0100] "GET /var/satellite/rhn/kickstart/sl_netinst/.treeinfo HTTP/1.1" 404 4715 "-" "curl/7.29.0"
10.10.10.6 - - [15/Jan/2017:12:39:00 +0100] "GET /var/satellite/rhn/kickstart/sl_netinst/LiveOS/squashfs.img HTTP/1.1" 404 4715 "-" "curl/7.29.0"
```

```
-rw-r-xr-x. 1 777 root 282337280 Jan 13 23:48 /var/satellite/rhn/kickstart/sl_netinst/LiveOS/squashfs.img
```

Can someone help me troublshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I think the below won't actually work, it keeps throwing an annaconda transaction error when installing packages. To actuall fix my issue I set my media_path to the following:

`/ks/dist/org/1/CentOS-7.3-Base`

The media_path variable in the "kickstart distribution" and the actual kickstart file were different.

**Kickstart Distribution --> Variables:** media_path=/ks/dist/org/1/CentOS-7.3-Base

**Kickstart Profiles --> Variables:** media_path=/var/satellite/rhn/kickstart/1/CentOS-7.3-Base

---

I solved this by doing the following (its actually quite easy)

1. Create a symlink under `/var/www/html` which points to your media directory. (I just called my symlink `centos7` here, and your symlink will point to  `/var/satellite/rhn/kickstart/sl_netinst/`)

   `ln -s /var/satellite/rhn/kickstart/1/CentOS-7.3-Base /var/www/html/centos7`
2. You then need to update your media_path variable in your kickstart. You can do this via the Spacewalk WebUI.

   **Kickstart Details -> Variables**

   and change `media_path` to centos7 (or name of your symlink)

[image: spacewalk webui]

3. Save your kickstart and boot again
4. You can also test that it works by trying to pull the squashfs.img.

   `curl -o squashfs.img <spacewalk_server>/centos7/LiveOS/squashfs.img`

**Why this works**

If you look at the default apache spacewalk configuration `/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz-spacewalk-www.conf`. It has this config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/*">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

So basically follow any symlinks under /var/www/html/ which is openly accessible by default.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Patrick.

the reason why this happenned in the first place is because i made a channel and kickstartable tree against the rolling CentoS 7 release. 
The kickstartable tree showed an invalid sign afterwards

When i choose to create a channel and kickstartable tree against CentOS7.3
All worked instantly